# How to getPackageName() without the 'applicationIdSuffix' defined in the buildTypes?

Tags: android

I want to get the package name of my android project without the buildTypes suffixed.

Example:

> com.newproject.name

is the applicationId of my project and the different buildTypes suffixed are:

> com.newproject.name.build1
>
> com.newproject.name.build2

getPackageName() method returns the package name along with the build type,which I dont want.

Without using RegEx, is there any way to get it?

Comment: Why you don't want regex ?

Comment: @vincrichaud why do you want regex?

Comment: @ZUNJAE I didn't say I want regex

Comment: @vincrichaud I don't want regex because in my project there are many build types and I don't want to add regex for each build type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all packages follow the same format

```
int positionOfLastDot = packageName.lastIndexOf('.');
return packageName.substring(0, positionOfLastDot)
```

Comment: this is not a perfect solution.
I use applicationIdSuffix ".build.dev" and ".build"

Comment: My comment was a solution to the original problem. I did not write the comment to solve your specific issue. @Kernelzero. Stop being lazy and write your own implementation

Comment: ok. sorry for that but I wanted to know how to get original packageName without processing. have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no direct solution but maybe this is ok for you:

```
getPackageName().replace( "." + BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE , "" );
```

Comment: This one's great!

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
String name = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
```

Comment: This will not give the right solution and I already mentioned this in my question.